# Bring HVAC Ducts to the Ground?

Tags: hvac

I'm finishing my basement. Is there any benefit to bringing the vents from the basement ceiling to the ground after I finish framing?

[image: Basement duct]

[image: Basement duct full view]

Comment: DANGER! That plastic in front of the insulation is wrong and will cause mold! Remove it! You need to read this: http://www.greenbuildingadvisor.com/blogs/dept/musings/how-insulate-basement-wall

Comment: Good to know. Thanks. The house came like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. Historically, registers and radiators have been by windows since in cold climates, they're the biggest sources of heat loss and discomfort. With the advent of Low-E double and triple pane windows, this concern is greatly diminished. That said, unless there's a *problem* with your ductwork, I don't see any advantage to moving the ducts.

Comment: I personally like 'em up high; that way they can't get blocked by furniture and stuff.